# Multiplication error in php

Tags: php, echo, multiplication

I'm building a site where people can exchange coins (site currency) into Bitcoin. The problem I'm having is that for some reason when I multiply the `$btcprice` with 3 or less the echo is really weird... for your sake this is the code that matters:

```
<?php
// get 0,01 usd in bitcoins into a variable
$btcprice = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.01');
$valueInBTC = 4 * $btcprice;
echo $valueInBTC; 
?>
```

Anything that's 4 or higher will work, but if you try to multiply this with 3 or less it gets weird. For example this:

```
<?php
// get 0,01 usd in bitcoins into a variable
$btcprice = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.01');
$valueInBTC = 3 * $btcprice;
echo $valueInBTC; 
?>
```

Will echo 7.959E-5

I just don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: I don't think you should be handling currency

Comment: What's the value of `$bctprice` prior to the multiplication?

Comment: Sounds as if you need to properly convert the incoming var into what you expect to use it as, ie not a string but a float or an integer, then echo out the vars, then do the computation, then format it to the level of accuracy you want it. 10.99 or whatever.

Comment: `7.959E-5` is correct.

Comment: Hahaha PeeHaa, don't worry I'm not building a bank. It's a membership points kinda site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are getting is not an error. It is simply in a formatting you don't expect / know yet. `7.959E-5`is exactly the same as `0.00007959` it is just a different way of writing it down. Think of it as `7.959E-5 = 7.959 × (10 ^ (-5)) = 0.00007959`. It is called [Scientific notation (E notation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). In cumputation / science this notation is used, because you can show very large or very small (as in your case) numbers with less digits (it is just shorter to write).

To get the number in other formattings use the php function [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

As you are handling bitcoin values, you shouldn't be formatiing the numbers until just for output. With bitcoins you always deal with very small numbers and you will soon meet precision problems if you try and calculate with formatted [floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.float.php).

Comment: Oh man you have no idea how incredibly stupid I feel now. Thanks for that... :D

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this is a formatting issue. You can simply use `printf`

```
printf("%.2f",$valueInBTC);
```

Another good option is to use `number_format();`
Eg:

```
$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```